# Jquery upload function doesn't work for multiple images on 1 page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload, fancybox

**How it works:**
I'm trying to create an instant upload function with Jquery/Ajax. When a user double-clicks an image, a Fancybox shows up with the upload field. After choosing an image, the image is uploaded and the source of the clicked image is changed immediately.

**The problem:**
When having multiple images on one page, sometimes another image gets replaced by the new image (randomly).

**The code:**

```
function uploader(thumb) {
new AjaxUpload('imageUpload', {
    action: 'uploader.php',
    name: 'file',
    onComplete: function(file, response) {
        thumb.attr('src', response);
        $.fancybox.close();
    }
});
}

$("img").dblclick(function(){
    var img = $(this);
    $.fancybox({
        href: '#imageUpload',
        overlayShow: true
    });
    uploader(img);
    return false;
});
```

**What I've tried:**
When I alert the ID of the image that should be replaced, it always alerts the correct ID of the image. And still it replaces another image instead.

Regards,
Bo

Comment: put a breakpoint right before the `src` switch and see if `thumb` is pointing to the right element

Comment: I added this: `alert(thumb.attr('id'));` before the `src` switch. It alerts the wrong ID indeed. But how to solve this? It appears `$(this);` isn't passed correctly to the `uploader()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're getting a reference to the clicked image is not good. You should extract the clicked element from the event object passed to the handler.

```
$('img').dblclick(function(event) {
   var img = $(event.target);
   ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but I get the same result. When I alert `img.attr('id')` after the code above, it always gives the right ID. But it's 'lost' in the `uploader()` function.